# Upload project to empty gitlab repo to dev branch

Tags: git, version-control, gitlab

I have an empty repo in Gitlab with two empty branches master and dev.

I want to push my local project to the dev branch instead of master

So I tried below

```
git init
git remote add origin <url>

git add .

git commit -m"Init"
git push origin dev
```

and the last step shows

```
error: src refspec dev does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to <url>
```

I have also tried to do

```
git checkout dev
```

after

```
git remote add origin <url>
```

but same error is showing

```
error: src refspec dev does not match any
```

I don't understand why it can't see the dev branch

I need to push the project to dev first then create a merge request to master.
I'm very beginner to git. And I have read many questions here about pushing to remote repo but all of them are pushing to the master/main branch

Comment: Use `git checkout -b dev` to create the branch and check it out at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't understand why it can't see the dev branch

Because you don't have a **local** branch `dev`. After `git init && git add && git commit` you have a local branch `master` (or may be `main`). So if you want to push it to remote branch `dev` the correct syntax is

```
git push origin master:dev
```

That means "push **local** branch `master` to **remote** branch `dev`". See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203).

It's a bit inconvenient to push to a branch with a different name so you can simplify your life a bit by renaming your local branch to `dev`:

```
git branch -m dev
```

See the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m).

After that

```
git push origin dev
```

works because it means "push **local** branch `dev` to **remote** branch `dev`".

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will give it a try. However after i did git remote add origin i run the command git fetch , then git checkout dev then add & commit & push and it got pushed to dev! But do you think this is a bad way or it will cause me issue down the line or is it fine?

Comment: After `git checkout dev` you're now on a different `dev` — the one you've fetched from `origin`. You'd better verify your commits were really pushed.

Comment: Ok I got you. But that’s strange because I checked it in the repo the commits were pushed to the dev in remote but still worried if this is not the right way. During push I did “git push origin dev” not sure if that makes any difference.